# Which consulting company can review our SonarQube installation?

Tags: sonarqube

Which good SonarQube consulting company could you recommend, that can review our SonarQube installation and processes?

We could even be open to having them take on the whole management of our installation.

Comment: You could contact the [creator](https://www.sonarsource.com/company/contact/) of SonarQube.

Answer (score 1):

Use the official hosted SonarQube instance called [SonarCloud](http://sonarcloud.io). It is maintained by SonarSource (the organization behind SonarQube) and can be used for both open source and closed source projects.